# JQuery regex validation not to allow some special character

Tags: jquery, regex, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying use JQuery regex validation for a textbox which should allow alphabetic letters, numbers and *SHOULD NOT* allow specific special characters like `<>'";:`.

Based on the previous questions, I used `/^[a-z0-9/.\#!%&~ -]+$/i` that allowed only these mentioned special characters.

I admit that this might seem like a duplicate question, but unfortunately I did not find those examples where only certain special characters *SHOULD NOT* be allowed. Please help me out with this.

Comment: What is the problem with your `regex`?

Comment: It works fine right?? It will not accept `<>'";:`

Comment: Yes. I want to make @ character to be allowed. But with the above specified Regex, I was unable to use @ character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order not to allow some specific set of symbols, you need a *negated character class* that is formed with the help of square brackets with `^` symbol right after the opening square bracket.

```
^[^<>'";:]+$
```

This regex will only allow characters other than the ones specified in the character class. Note that `-`, `]` and `[` should either be at the start or end of the character class, or you will have to escape them.

See more details about [character classes on Regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Comment: Please feel free to drop a line if you have any further issues with this regex.